# Is Advance Wars Days of Ruin compatible with Dark Conflict

Tags: advance-wars

I bought a copy on Amazon hoping to play my friend who has Days of Ruin (both are from the same generation, one is from Europe and the other is US) will we be able to play multiplayer together?

Comment: Interesting question. The only difference between the two games is the translation so I guess the question comes down to whether the consoles communicate using things that were translated or only IDs

Comment: In a perfect software situation locale would have no bearing on the netcode so both would be able to communicate without knowing they were actually different. However this is is the real world the so all I can say is give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought Dark conflict, and I have verified that it works with Days of Ruin (I have played many times with a friend who owns Days of Ruin).